# How to add a new element to a hashset that is value of a ConcurrentDictionary?

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I have a ConcurrentDictionary that has as key a long and as value a hashset of int. I want that if the key isn't in the dictionary, add a new hashset with the first element. If the key exists, add the new element to the existing dictionary.

I am trying something like that:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<long, HashSet<int>> myDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, HashSet<int>>();
int myElement = 1;
myDic.AddOrUpdate(1, new Hashset<int>(){myFirstElement},
(key, actualValue) => actualValue.Add(myElement));
```

The problem with this code is the third parameter, because .Add() method returns a bool and the AddOrUpdate expects a hashset. The first and second parameters are right.

So my question is how I can add a new element to the hashset in thread-safe way and avoid duplicates (it is the reason why I am using a hashset as value). The problem of the hashset is that it is not thread-safe and if I get it first and later add the new element, I am doing outside of the dictionary and I could have problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix compiler error you can do this:

```
myDic.AddOrUpdate(1, new HashSet<int>() { myFirstElement },
    (key, actualValue) => {
        actualValue.Add(myFirstElement);
        return actualValue;
    });
```

**BUT** this is not thread safe, because "update" function is not run inside any lock so you are potentially adding to not-thread-safe `HashSet` from multiple threads. This might result in (for example) losing values (so you were adding 1000 items to `HashSet` but in the end you have only 970 items in it for example). Update function in `AddOrUpdate` should not have any side effects and here it does.

You can lock yourself over adding values to `HashSet`:

```
myDic.AddOrUpdate(1, new HashSet<int>() { myFirstElement },
    (key, actualValue) => {
        lock (actualValue) {
            actualValue.Add(myFirstElement);
            return actualValue;
        }
    });
```

But then question is why you are using lock-free structure (`ConcurrentDictionary`) in the first place. Besides that - any other code might get `HashSet` from your dictionary and add value there without any locks, making the whole thing useless. So if you decide to go that way for some reason - you have to ensure that all code locks when accessing `HashSet` from that dictionary.

Instead of all that - just use concurrent collection instead of `HashSet`. There is no `ConcurrentHashSet` as far as I know but you can use another `ConcurrentDictionary` with dummy keys as a replacement (or look over internet for custom implementations).

Side note. Here

```
myDic.AddOrUpdate(1, new Hashset<int>(){myFirstElement},
```

you create new `HashSet` every time when calling `AddOrUpdate`, even if that dictionary is not needed because key is already there. Instead use overload with add value factory:

```
myDic.AddOrUpdate(1, (key) => new HashSet<int>() { myFirstElement },
```

Edit: sample usage of `ConcurrentDictionary` as hash set:

```
var myDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte>>();
long key = 1;
int element = 1;
var hashSet = myDic.AddOrUpdate(key, 
    _ => new ConcurrentDictionary<int, byte>(new[] {new KeyValuePair<int, byte>(element, 0)}),
    (_, oldValue) => {
        oldValue.TryAdd(element, 0);
        return oldValue;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your tips. Could you wirte an example how I could use a CouncurrentDictionary as value with dummy keys? Thanks.

Comment: In this example. Between I get the hashset and I try to add the new element, someone could delete it, so when I try to add I could get an error., or at least I would add an element to a hashet that there is no in the dictionary. Is it correct?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Yes that is correct (no error but you will add to hashset no longer there). If that is a problem for you - I think you can use AddOrUpdate as you did originally (with ConcurrentDictionary instead of HashSet of course).

Comment: I was thinking that, do the first way with your side note and change dictionary instead of hashset. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the anonymous function definition in curly braces, you can define multiple statements in the body of the function and thus specify the return value like this:

```cs
myDic.AddOrUpdate(1, new HashSet<int>() { myFirstElement },
(key, actualValue) => {
    actualValue.Add(myElement);
    return actualValue;
});
```